# How would you say "same thing" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary

How would you say "same thing" in Latin? As in the sentence: If only you were feeling the same thing that I feel for you?

Answer (score 4):

This is best expressed with the neuter pronoun *idem*, "same", in Latin.
For example:

> *Utinam idem sentires ac ipsa/ipse sentio!*
>   If only you felt the same as I (fem/masc) feel!

Alternatively, you could use the plural *eadem*, "same things".
The difference in meaning is not huge, and Latin tends to favour plurals here more than English.

Latin doesn't usually use a noun for "thing" the same way English and many other languages do.
Instead, a pronoun or an adjective in neuter is used.

I assume you were only after an expression for "same thing" here.
If you want to find a good way to phrase the "for you" in "what I feel for you" in Latin, I recommend asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I want to pick up on Joonas' answer, and just provide the sentence with the literal translation for "same thing":

> *Utinam sentires eandem rem quam sentio tibi*

Whilst this might not be very common or appropriate for the particular context,  *eadem res* is a valid expression in Roman Law (see top of page [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oR0LAAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA460&ots=sUNtW_gCcG&dq=eadem%20res&pg=PA447#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Comment: Interesting! Do you know whether *res* should be construed as a general "thing" or more like "case" or some other specific meaning in legal use?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta For what I can see, seems to refer to the thing to which the aspect of the law is relevant. In the case of a trial, is the case or matter under judgment. Perhaps is not that pertinent for other type of "things". In any case, I found one instance (haven't searched for more) of a use which seems to be more general than a legal context in Aquinas' _Summa Theologiae_ (see point 4 [here](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/sth1015.html#29105)).