# Is ipsum/ipsa/ipse a third person pronoun, or can it serve other functions?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

This question was inspired by a comment to an answer on this question:

[How would you say “same thing” in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/how-would-you-say-same-thing-in-latin/)

In which an answerer translated "Utinam idem sentires ac **ipsa/ipse** sentio!" as "If only you felt the same as **I** (fem/masc) feel!"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

As Joonas said, *ipse* is an intensifier, not a pronoun in and of itself.

> *Caesar ipse hoc dixit.*
>   Caesar *himself* said this!

The trick is, Latin leaves out pronouns all the time. So you'll sometimes see *ipse* standing on its own.

> *Ipse hoc aedificavi.*
>   I built this *myself*!

Here, the ending of the verb is what supplies the "I" and "my-" parts.

Finally, a word of caution: *ipse* does **not** mean "-self" in the sense of "he's talking to himself". In English, the "intensive" pronoun and the "reflexive" pronoun look the same, but in Latin this isn't the case! So only use *ipse* when you're emphasizing something, *not* when you're saying that the subject and the object are the same.

Comment: I would actually say that *ipse* is a pronoun, but not a personal pronoun. But I guess that depends on what one means by a pronoun in a first place, and that's tangential to the question at hand. Anyway, a +1 for a good explanation!

Answer (score 4):

The pronoun *ipse* is not a third person pronoun.
It can be used with the first or second person just as well.
The closest English word I can think of is "-self" from which one can form "myself", "yourself", "himself", and others.
(For clarity, I should add that *ipse* is not quite the same as "-self"; it is just the simplest one-word translation. Forms of *se* can also be translated as "-self", but in a very different way.)

Reference to first or second (or third!) person can be left implicit.
You can say *ipse sentio* ("I myself feel"), no need to say *ego ipse sentio*.

It is possible to use it together with *ego* or *tu* as well, and that gives more emphasis.
It also proves unambiguously that the pronoun can go together with first and second persons.
For a couple of examples, you can check uses of [*ego ipse*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=ego+ipse+%5Bcic%5D) and [*tu ipse*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=tu+ipse+%5Bcic%5D) in Cicero.

Comment: That has to be the fastest answer in history (literally within seconds haha). I will mark yours as the answer as soon as it'll allow me (which is apparently 10 minutes from now) (Also, did you mean to write "*un*ambiguously?")

Comment: @SolaGratia I did, but I was in a Latin mode and went with in- instead of un-. Good catch!