# Translate "Rise above yourself" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to ask you for help with double-checking the translation of "Rise above yourself", as in "surpass your own self". In feminine form would this be *Supergreditur ipsum*?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi! It seems that you have created two accounts. Please [see the instructions for merging them](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). After doing so you can more easily interact with anyone who answers you, accepting the best answer and voting up any questions and answers you like after reaching 15 reputation points yourself.

Answer (score 3):

How about **transcende te ipsum**? Or, if the person if question is indeed female, **transcende te ipsam**.

*transcende* is the imperative singular of *transcendere* (to transcend, surpass), *te* is the accusative singular second person personal pronoun ("you" as the direct object of a verb), *ipsum* (masculine) or *ipsam* (feminine) are the accusative singular reflexive pronouns (adding the meaning of "-self"). So this means quite literally "surpass yourself".
[As stated by Sebastian Koppehel in comments below, this is an oversimplification; technically, *te* is the second person reflexive pronoun in this case, and *ipsum*/*ipsam* are intensifiers, which in this case serve to clarify that *te* is reflexive.]

The sentence also has a close parallel with the well-known phrase *nosce te ipsum* (know thyself), which itself is a translation of the famous Greek phrase γνῶθι σεαυτόν (gnōthi seauton) inscribed on the temple of Apollo at Delphi.

Comment: *ipsam* surely?

Comment: In addition to what @Sebastian said, can you explain what your suggestion means? The OP (original poster) doesn't seem to have much prior knowledge of Latin, so an explanation would be helpful, also about genders. But I do fully agree: this is a great translation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply
Yes, unfortunately I never had an opportunity to learn Latin and I am trying to prepare small project for my friend.

Comment: Super pedantic carping: *te* is the reflexive pronoun in this sentence (although yes, it is the accusative of *tu*; the difference would be visible in the third person, where we would have *se*, not *eam*). *Ipse* [is not a reflexive pronoun](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9440/is-ipsum-ipsa-ipse-a-third-person-pronoun-or-can-it-serve-other-functions) *except* when it stands in for the nominative of *se*. This is why we cannot leave out *te* here in my opinion.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel you're of course quite right, I oversimplified. In my opinion, neither _te_ nor _ipsum_ can be omitted, because the second person reflexive pronoun _te_ requires the _ipsum_ for clarity.

Comment: The *ipsam* is not required, but emphasises the reflexive nature of the exhortation. For example, when Cicero tells Catilina: "Confer te ad Manlium [...] secerne te a bonis" (1st Catilinarian), he does not use it, and it would sound weird if he did. Here Latin differs from English, where the emphatically reflexive *yourself* is the only option.

Comment: In this case, I feel the _ipsam_ is required. In my opinion, Latin and German are much alike in this regard; certainly, a German translation would be "übertriff Dich selbst", not "übertriff dich", whereas in the Ciceronian example, a German translation would not use _selbst_. This is indeed different from English, where _-self_ is the only way to express reflexivity.