When to use "x-is-the-same-as-y" or "x-is-like-y"?
Continuing from Q: How Would "Chemical Weapons" be expressed in Latin?, to translate this expression:

"I think that developing chemical weapons would be tantamount to selling one's soul to the Devil,"

is "tantamount to"/ "equivalent to" a case of "x-is-the-same-as-y" ("idem ac") as in Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/9434/1982; or, "x-is-like-y" ("veluti") as in Q: How would one say "such as" or "like" as prepositions?
For example:

"cogito fingentia arma venenorum essent idem ac [selling one's soul],

is this (partial) translation correct?
